# How to stop threads that are in wait state for user request

Tags: c#, multithreading

[image: Memory Usage after 3-4 functions]

[image: Threads after 2 forms open and closed and 2 different processes started one of them is closed]

Recently I created a wpf application that will not be stopped by user.
 I used spy++ to see how many threads are there.
The issue is it creates many threads(average all time threads are 15-17 whether app is minimized or not) I have seen upto 23 and when application is minimized those threads are not stopped they are just in wait state (reason - user request), so not freeing the memory.
I have tried many things like disposing manually, closing forms and applications. I have not created these threads so I dont know how do I kill these threads.

What I am doing now is when user minimizes the application I am calling close method of other window forms manually. so a little bit of memory is cleaned.
My worry is Its minimum 92MB when its doing nothing just sitting in the background. it reaches to 180 MB, If I perform some functions.

Please anyone can advice me on this. How do I stop these threads and free the memory.Please let me know if there is any need of my code related to anything. I will post that. And please before a negative vote have a clarification with me If I have done anything or not.

I have read when people minimize their memory usage decrease upto 5 times sometimes... But its not same here.. The memory uses are near about same.(only 10-30MB freed)

Update: Added screenshots from spy++ . I closed all the forms and only one other processes is running after this. Then also It stayed at 21 threads.

Comment: These threads probably belong to the [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Have you looked at [Cancellation Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)?

Comment: I am looking into both Cancellation Tokens and Thread Pool if I can find something of use.

Comment: Ok, you have threads. But do you actually have a problem? What is not functioning, how?

Comment: @bommelding.. The issue is that the application is going to run on a Multimedia Controlling device that wont have much memory to run large memory using app along with other necessary apps. So I just want to remove as much memory as it can be freed when the application is not doing anything.

Comment: @J.vanLangen I was thinking is there any way to get these threads and its wait reason. If application is minimized and wait reason is user request it can be stopped. As these are manages by OS these will be created again when user wants to perform some functionality. Am I right? Is there anything like that

Comment: You cannot control the threads way you are expecting and ideally you shouldn't bother at all, these are pool thread which are surely used for other tasks too. You haven't posted code, but easier way is to minimize your thread / Task usage, which is in fact leading to more threads. Also not all threads are foreground threads, some of them can be background, which have nothing to do with your application as such. Not sure about Spy++, but checkout Sysinternals Process explorer, which has much more detailed information. Also Cancellation token is of no use here, that's cooperative cancellation

Comment: I still don't think you have a problem, and certainly not one you can solve this way. Profile your app and see what uses memory. But 180 MB is not a lot, it's mostly virtual anyway.

Comment: `I have read when people minimize their memory usage decrease upto 5 times sometimes... But its not same here.. The memory uses are near about same.(only 10-30MB freed)` Those people are monitoring the physical memory, which is pretty much worthless. It goes down when the app is minimized because Windows tends to aggressively swap them out to leave more physical memory to foreground applications. This is OS voodoo, you shouldn't have to care about it. What you need to monitor is private memory for your process

Comment: Thank you all for your help.. I think you all are right. I shouldnt be worried about this thing. as These is managed by system. And yes..  I have examined. I left my application idle for 1 hour or more... Then  it was a lot less memory usage after that, but threads were the same. So I think it threads were in waiting state but not using memory at that time. So in future it wont cause much issue.